# Elementary Calculus Substition Problem

Tags: calculus

It's been awhile since I've done single-variable calculus and I'm embarassed to say that I can't even understand how the following equality holds. If someone could provide a step-by-step explanation of how this equality holds, I'd appreciate it:

$\int \frac{1}{(v-1)(v+1)}dv = - \int \frac{1}{2u+1}du$

where we have substitution of $u = \dfrac{1}{v-1} \implies \dfrac{du}{dv} = - \dfrac{1}{(v-1)^2}$.

I understand how the substition works but I don't understand how to get $- \int \frac{1}{2u+1}du$ from the substitution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An advice to resolve almost all integrals of quotients of polynomials is to use long division whenever possible, and if not possible, partial fractions(of course, you would have to factor the denominator to do partial fractions). I also remember had developed a formula for the primitive of $\dfrac{1}{Ax^2+Bx+C}$, in function of A, B and C. It ain't so hard to deduce, and it is very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $$\frac{du}{dv} = -\frac{1}{(v-1)^2} = -\left(\frac{1}{v-1}\right)^2 = -u^2 $$
$$\implies dv = \frac{-du}{u^2}.$$

Also,

$$u = \frac{1}{v-1}$$
$$\implies v-1 = \frac{1}{u}$$
$$\implies v+1 = \frac{1}{u}+2 = \frac{2u+1}{u}$$
$$\implies \frac{1}{v+1} = \frac{u}{2u+1}$$

Putting it all together,
$$\int \frac{1}{(v-1)(v+1)}dv = \int \frac{1}{v-1}\cdot\frac{1}{v+1}dv = \int u \cdot \frac{u}{2u+1} \cdot \frac{-du}{u^2} = -\int \frac{1}{2u+1}du$$

Comment: That is perfectly lucid. Thank you so much for putting in the time to write this out for me. Cheers.

Comment: No problem! Sometimes a $u$-sub problem of this type involves a little work to get everything in terms of $u$ as opposed to the $u$-sub problems of the easier variety where everything just cancels nicely :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$u=\frac{1}{v-1}$ implies that $\frac{1}{v+1}=\frac{u}{2u+1}$.
And as you've mentioned, $du=-\frac{1}{(v-1)^2} dv=-u^2 dv$. Thus, $dv=-\frac{1}{u^2}du$.
Substitute all of these to your integral, you'll get the answer.